# VB.net if Day(Now) = 1

Tags: vb.net

I want this program to do something on a certain day (birthday)
I have tried

```
If Date.Day(Now) = 1 And Month(Now) = 3 Then
  MsgBox("Happy Birthday!")
End If
```

But `Date.Day(Now)` does not appear to be correct (`Month(Now)` works fine).
The error is:

> Operator '=' is not defined for types 'Date' and 'Integer'

Comment: not related to the problem but you should keep  `And` for bitwise computation and use `AndAlso` instead to chain logical proposition (same with `Or` and `OrElse`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the NET Framework [DateTime structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and its properties instead

```
If DateTime.Now.Day = 13 And DateTime.Now.Month = 9 Then
    Console.WriteLine("Happy Birthday!")
End If
```

As hinted below in the comments, you are mixing calls to the VB6 compatibility library (Month(Now) from Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll) and calls to DateTime structure (Date alias), but the DateTime structure doesn't have a shared member called Day, instead it has a shared property named Now and from this property you can extract the Day value.

If you insist in using the Microsoft.VisualBasic compatibility library then your code should be

```
If Day(Now) = 13 And Month(Now) = 9 Then
.....
```

Comment: he's already using it (for the Day part at least), `Date` is an alias for `DateTime` type

Comment: @xXH4CK3RXx this would be a great time to try out your new power to Upvote questions *or* answers (anywhere) which you find helpful.  This helps other users find good answers.  The [Tour] explains more in very brief fashion.,